# 404 Page Not Found codeigniter, controller not detected

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have some problem, I was access this link http://awd.esy.es/index.php/atlet_goal/save_physical/atlet/fashah

cannot found the controller, I try on localhost is run but on server is not run. I have controller file Atlet_Goal.php on controller folder. The Code Is :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Atlet_Goal extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model('M_Data');
}

public function save_physical() {
    if($this->session->userdata('login')){
        $session = $this->session->userdata('login');
        $get = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(1);
        $atlet = $get['atlet'];
        $current_dttm = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['master_user_username'] = $session['master_user_username'];
        $data['master_user_name'] = $session['master_user_name'];
        $data['master_user_unique_id'] = $session['master_user_unique_id'];

        $nama_komponen  = $_POST['input_name'];
        $nilai_komponen = $_POST['input_nilai'];

        $data = array(
                'username' => $session['master_user_username'],
                'atlet' => $atlet,
                'dttm' => $current_dttm,
                'komponen' => $nama_komponen,
                'value' => $nilai_komponen
        );

        $save = $this->M_Data->save_physical_goal($data);

        if($save){
            redirect('home/set_training_goal','refresh');
        }else{
            echo "gagal";
        }
    }else{
        redirect('login','refresh');   
    }


}

public function save_technical()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('login')){
        $session = $this->session->userdata('login');
        $get = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(1);
        $atlet = $get['atlet'];
        $current_dttm = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['master_user_username'] = $session['master_user_username'];
        $data['master_user_name'] = $session['master_user_name'];
        $data['master_user_unique_id'] = $session['master_user_unique_id'];

        $nama_komponen  = $_POST['input_name'];
        $nilai_komponen = $_POST['input_nilai'];

        $data = array(
                'username' => $session['master_user_username'],
                'atlet' => $atlet,
                'dttm' => $current_dttm,
                'komponen' => $nama_komponen,
                'value' => $nilai_komponen
        );

        $save = $this->M_Data->save_technical_goal($data);

        if($save){
            redirect('home/set_training_goal','refresh');
        }else{
            echo "gagal";
        }
    }else{
        redirect('login','refresh');   
    }       
}



 public function save_mental()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('login')){
        $session = $this->session->userdata('login');
        $get = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(1);
        $atlet = $get['atlet'];
        $current_dttm = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['master_user_username'] = $session['master_user_username'];
        $data['master_user_name'] = $session['master_user_name'];
        $data['master_user_unique_id'] = $session['master_user_unique_id'];

        $nama_komponen  = $_POST['input_name'];
        $nilai_komponen = $_POST['input_nilai'];

        $data = array(
                'username' => $session['master_user_username'],
                'atlet' => $atlet,
                'dttm' => $current_dttm,
                'komponen' => $nama_komponen,
                'value' => $nilai_komponen
        );

        $save = $this->M_Data->save_mental_goal($data);

        if($save){
            redirect('home/set_training_goal','refresh');
        }else{
            echo "gagal";
        }
    }else{
        redirect('login','refresh');   
    }       
}


public function logout(){
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('login');
    redirect('home','refresh');
}

public function set(){
    $get = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(1);
    $set = $get['data'];
    $data['set'] = $set;
    $this->load->view('v_data',$data);
}
}
```

And error display 404 page not found, can you help me?

Comment: check your config file set $config['index]="index.php" or not

Comment: yes, like this one $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: yes, are you use .htaccess

Comment: yes my $config['index'] is  'index.php'

Comment: i use default .htaccess codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter Controller name and controller file name should only first letter Capital

```
change file name to "atlet_goal.php" and controller name to "Atlet_goal"
```

or use url like

```
http://awd.esy.es/index.php/atlet_Goal/save_physical/atlet/fashah
```